# does fields_for create form per resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a Person model that has_many addresses. If in the controller I do 3.times{@person.addresses.build}, should the following code generate 3 sets of text_fields for address?  For some reason I'm only getting 1 address form, regardless of how many addresses I build in the controller. I'm using Rails 3.0

```
 <%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
    <%= person_form.fields_for :addresses do |address_fields| %>
      Street  : <%= address_fields.text_field :street %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses` on the Person model?

Comment: The answer is yes, it will create one person_form for each address the person has (either persisted or not). Try debug(@person.addresses) to confirm there are 3 entries in the array when it hits the rendering page.

Comment: I did this in my view <%= @person.addresses.inspect %> in my view and indeed 3 addresses show up. For some reason the fields_for doesn't even care about what I built. I can even build nothing at all and it still renders 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your fields_for block inside of an each loop, and pass each instance as an argument to fields_for. For example:

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  <% @person.addresses.each do |address| %>  
    <%= person_form.fields_for :addresses, address do |address_fields| %>
      Street  : <%= address_fields.text_field :street %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Alternately, you can pass a collection as an argument to fields_for and have it iterate automatically:

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  <%= person_form.fields_for :addresses, @person.addresses do |address_fields| %>
    Street  : <%= address_fields.text_field :street %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and it DOES work. However, I would still like to get my original method working since the syntax is cleaner.

Comment: I'm actually not sure where the @address variable comes from, I haven't defined it anywhere but it works. For some reason the second suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: It throws this error: "Model Array does not respond to street"

Comment: Interesting. Anyway, I've bookmarked this page, it might be helpful in future. Thanks for sharing the issue.

Comment: Also, the 3 input fields generated by the first suggestion all have the same html id... I thought id's had to be unique??

Comment: Try to replace `@address` with just `address` in the first suggestion

Comment: As maprihoda mentions, I made an error with my example. I have updated my example to show the correct variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

The form looks OK. According to the documentation (`ri fields_for`), you need to have both the `addresses` reader and writer methods in the Person model. You already have the reader method (because you stated that the Person has_many :addresses), so now you need the writer method - you can either create it 'manually' (`def addresses_attributes=(...)`) or let `accepts_nested_attributes_for` define the writer for you.

Comment: I have accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses defined. Removing/adding isn't changing anything tho.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses` in your `Person` model. Second, using `build` will really just build but not save records. If you want to keep this example, go on with something like this:

```
3.times { @person.addresses.create }
```

Comment: `@person.addresses.build` is correct because he just wants to display the form, not to save the addresses (he will save them by posting the form to the create method)

Comment: Uh, that's news to me. Always thought `build` just returns an unsaved record with, in this case, `person_id` already set. Didn't know it adds the object directly to the association array.

Comment: Yeah, `build` creates an unsaved object in memory and automatically set the foreign key (person_id) which it infers from the association. And that's all what's needed to render the form - ie the form helpers need some instance, even though it's an unsaved instance hanging somewhere in memory, to render correctly.